# How to get all data in one page

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and I need To export all data to Excel, but spring by default returns data in a page.

How can me return all data in one page even if the number of entities would exceed the maximum page size of 2147483647?

Answer (score 0):

If you call [findAll()](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#findAll--) without `Pageable` as parameter it will return a `List<T>` which contains all entities of that repository.

Comment: I'm using query Dsl and binding how to add Pageable into it  ?

Comment: @EmadJoha Does my answer solve your original problem?

Comment: no the Original  problem was with querydsl not without them Thank You!